# How do I combine the AND and OR operator in a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

My goal is to find out if certain combinations of keywords that could be present in a column filled with text strings (titles of news articles). I then want to plot the frequency in a bar chart.

I have done the following, using a pandas data frame:

```
pvv_news = df[df['desc'].str.contains("pvv", case=True)]
pvv_month = win.groupby(win.index.month).size()
pvv_month.index = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June']
pvv_month.plot(kind='bar')
```

Which gives:

[image]

Now, what I can't figure out is how to make a combinations of AND and OR to get more specific results. Example of what I have in mind but what doesn't work:

```
pvv_news = df[df['desc'].str.contains("(pvv)&(nederland|overheid)", case=True)]
```

I've looked at the following functions but I can't figure it out:

- pandas.Series.str.extract
- pandas.Series.str.match
- pandas.Series.str.contains
- Regular expressions in combination with the above functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I'm following what you want to do, this should work:

```
pvv_news = df[(df['desc'].str.contains("pvv"), case = True) &
              ((df['desc'].str.contains("nederland"), case = True) |  
               (df['desc'].str.contains("overheid"), case = True)) ]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do, thank you! In general would you say that this is a logical way to search for key words in strings when using Pandas? And would I need to use regex when the keywords I was looking for are not the complete word in a string? i.e.: key word: American, string: Amercians

Comment: I think you can simplify this to : `pvv_news = df[(df['desc'].str.contains("pvv"), case = True) &
              (df['desc'].str.contains("nederland|overheid"), case = True) ]`

Comment: @EdChum Yep, I already did that and it works. I have to say I don't understand the logic behind allowing | but not & inside the "" though.

Comment: @Lam you should be able to pass a regex as the pattern and just use a single `contains` call

Comment: @EdChum Here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html it says to use re.search when you want to use regex in str.contains. Using re.search should follow re.search(pattern, string, flags=0) (https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search). How can I give the string parameter in this case?